# How to tell Googletrans to ignore certain parts?

Tags: python, google-translate, google-translation-api, googletrans

I would like to use `googletrans` to make use of the Google translate API. However, there are strings where are variable names in it:

```
User "%(first_name)s %(last_name)s (%(email)s)" has been deleted.
```

If I use this via googletrans I get

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
translator.translate(u'User "%(first_name)s %(last_name)s (%(email)s)" has been assigned.', src='en', dest='fr').text
```

I get the following:

```
L'utilisateur "% (first_name) s% (last_name) s (% (email) s)" a été affecté.
```

However, the "%(first_name) s% (last_name)s (%(email)s)" has some strings introduced. Is there a way around this? I've already tried:

```
u'User "<span class="notranslate">%(first_name)s %(last_name)s (%(email)s)</span>" has been assigned.'
```

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem you are facing?It's somewhat hard for me to read and understand what your actual problem is.

Comment: @math, did my answer solve your issue?  I could not find a documented way to exclude part of the text from translation (or being modified), but my answer should do the trick for your case unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Googletrans leaves, e.g., `__1__` untouched.  So you can replace `%(first_name)s` with `__0__`, `%(last_name)s` with `__1__`, etc. before you translate, and then restore the variables afterwards.  Here code to do this:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import re

translator = Translator()
txtorig = u'User "%(first_name)s %(last_name)s (%(email)s)" has been assigned.'

# temporarily replace variables of format "%(example_name)s" with "__n__" to
#  protect them during translate()
VAR, REPL = re.compile(r'%\(\w+\)s'), re.compile(r'__(\d+)__')
varlist = []
def replace(matchobj):
  varlist.append(matchobj.group())
  return "__%d__" %(len(varlist)-1)
def restore(matchobj):
  return varlist[int(matchobj.group(1))]

txtorig = VAR.sub(replace, txtorig)
txttrans = translator.translate(txtorig, src='en', dest='fr').text
txttrans = REPL.sub(restore, txttrans)

print(txttrans)
```

Here the result:

```
L'utilisateur "%(first_name)s %(last_name)s (%(email)s)" a été attribué.
```

Comment: Actually you need the following format:
(3 before) string (2 after)
___%s__


I got a problem with the following translation:
From Language code: 'en'
To Language code: 'si' 
Content: "You gave __1__ to __2__"
Result: ඔබ __2__ ට __2__ ලබා දුන්නා

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need the following format:

```
(3 '_' before) (string) (2 '_' after)
Like: ___%s__
```